# updating query every day using task scheduling in laravel

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to update a query every day using the laravel task scheduler. I currently have a home controller in which I select the picture with the most likes and pass the result to my home page. I also have started a windows task which calls my laravel schedule every minute.

HomeController:

```
$foodOfTheDay = Picture::withCount('likes')
    ->where('picture_type', 'food')
    ->orderBy('likes_count', 'desc')
    ->with('user')
    ->first();

$drinkOfTheDay = Picture::withCount('likes')
    ->where('picture_type', 'drink')
    ->orderBy('likes_count', 'desc')
    ->with('user')
    ->first();

return view('timeline.index', [
            'users' => $users,
            'pictures' => $pictures,
            'comments' => $comments,
            'foodOfTheDay' => $foodOfTheDay,               
            'drinkOfTheDay' => $drinkOfTheDay,
        ]);
```

Schedule:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();

   $schedule->call('\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@petsOfDay')->daily();
}
```

I'm wondering how I could update the food and drink of the day variables from my schedule all the while keeping them accessible to my home view.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly do you want to update with the `food` and `drink` variables? The way you can handle this problem largely depends on what you actually want to do with updating. Also just a heads up, from a best practice point of view it's not ideal to call your controllers directly with Laravel Scheduling, controllers should remain apart of the Request/Response cycle. Ideally you would create an `artisan` command to call in your scheduler.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but it isn't clear to me from your question why you need scheduling at all for this? Every time you hit your home page in a browser, you will get up-to-date, live results, fresh from the DB.

Comment: I was actually trying to show the most popular picture for a whole day before switching to the next day's most popular picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to create a command with `php artisan make:command YourCommandName`. This creates a file in `app/Console/Commands/`.

In the newly created Command file, change then `$signature` to something useful. Also, in the `handle()` method, write your logic there.

Next, you have to register the command in `$commands` array in `app/Console/Kernel.php`.

Finally, in the `schedule()` method of `app/Console/Kernel.php`, call your command with frequency e.g `$schedule->call('command:signature')->daily();`

PS: This assumes you already have a corn job set up on your server that runs every minute.

To solve the problem, create a new database table that stores the pictures of the day. Then, create an artisan command which uploads the food and drink variables. In a schedule, update the artisan command daily. Lastly, write a query in the controller that selects the most recent result from the picture of the day table for each category and pass the result of that query to the view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried using an artisan command, but I was unable to access the values of food and drink in my view. Is there a way to pass data to a view from a command?

Comment: What you can do is create a temp table that the command updates daily. Then you fetch data from that temp table in your controller method

Comment: sorry, but when you say a CRON job already set up on the server. means that you can't schedule this on Laravel without it?

Comment: Yes. In order for laravel scheduler to work, there must be a CRON job set up on your server to run `php artisan schedule:run` every minute. See more here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling